# Creating Application Scope objects Restful web service

Tags: web-services, rest, singleton, cxf

I have a few Restful web services made in [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/). I'm using the non-spring version of the CXFServlet. The logs for my web services go into a mongo database. Right now my web services are configured in such a way that everytime my web services are called, a new connection is created to connect the db. I want to configure the Mongo Client object in the application scope. So i get only one connection object shared between multiple web services. I looked at the [Apache CXF docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/) but could'nt get most of it. I had stumbled upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096310/singleton-object-in-java-web-service) about creating singleton objects, I don't know if that's true for my case. So I need a way to configure my logger as global object for the whole application.
 If there's a similar question already asked please give me a link to that

Comment: Don't use singletons! If you need to have a global object, use a global object. Just make absolutely sure that you actually need a global object.

Comment: @thecoshman: yes i need a global object, but why should'nt i use singletons?

Comment: Your problem is that you need a global object to access the DB. So make a single global object to access the DB.

Comment: OK, but how should i configure the global object in the cxf?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use cxf.

Comment: Finally did this by creating a separate Listener for the CXFServlet and added the Required Object in the ServletContext.