# How Can I store a XML object in a global session that can be reached every request?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-rs, jax-ws

Every night a XML document comes in a folder in the WS server. 
I want the web service to read this XML file at a certain time (let's say at 05:00) and place it in a object stored in memory, every day.

How can I achieve this? Which object should I use? 
I intend to use a JAX-WS. Could it be possible using JAX-RS too?

Tks.

Comment: If "storing a n XML file in a memory object" is all you need you might as well read the file into a byte array. If there's more to it, you should say so, e.g., Is the web service a single program? Does it need details from the XML document? Do you have an XML Schema for it? Etc. ...

Comment: It's just store in memory, until the next read (to update the data). I'll create some tests. tks

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as an attribute in the `ServletContext` of the application. It will be accessible to any JAX-WS services or JAX-RS resources in the web module. As an added bonus, if your JAX-WS service and JAX-RS resources are in the same module (war), they will share the same *instance* of the object/document you place there.

For the JAX-RS resource:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    @Context ServletContext context;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getMyResource() {
        return context.getAttribute("cachedDocument");
    }
}
```

For the JAX-WS service:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;

@WebService
public class MyService {
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;

    @WebMethod
    public String getDocument() {
        ServletContext servletContext =
    (ServletContext) context.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
        return servletContext.getAttribute("cachedDocument");
    }
}
```

See also: [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) javadocs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I was searching for something more like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096310/singleton-object-in-java-web-service, a singleton object loaded once and shared among all my web service threads. About your answer, is this context already instantiated or I need to init it manually? Tks.

Comment: Context is provided for you by the application server (container) runtime. To go the singleton route is to roll your own solution to a problem the spec authors solved years ago. Just my two cents.