# Apache Spark Sql issue in multi node hadoop cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am using Spark java apis to fetch data from hive. This code is working in hadoop single node cluster. But when I tried to use it in hadoop multi node cluster it throws error as

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Detected yarn-cluster mode, but isn't running on a cluster. Deployment to YARN is not supported directly by SparkContext. Please use spark-submit.
```

Note : I have used master as local for single node and yarn-cluster for multi node.

And this is my java code

```
 SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Hive").setMaster("yarn-cluster");
 JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
 HiveContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(ctx.sc());
org.apache.spark.sql.Row[] result = sqlContext.sql("Select * from Tablename").collect();
```

Also I have tried to change master as local and now it throws unknown hostname exception.
Can anyone help me in this?

**Updated**

Error logs

```
15/08/05 11:30:25 INFO Query: Reading in results for query "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery@0" since the connection used is closing
15/08/05 11:30:25 INFO ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
15/08/05 11:30:25 INFO HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
15/08/05 11:30:25 INFO HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
15/08/05 11:30:25 INFO HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
15/08/05 11:30:25 INFO SessionState: No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
15/08/05 11:30:25 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=default tbl=activity
15/08/05 11:30:25 INFO audit: ugi=labuser   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=activity 
15/08/05 11:30:25 WARN HiveConf: DEPRECATED: hive.metastore.ds.retry.* no longer has any effect.  Use hive.hmshandler.retry.* instead
15/08/05 11:30:25 INFO deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
15/08/05 11:30:26 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(399000) called with curMem=0, maxMem=1030823608
15/08/05 11:30:26 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 389.6 KB, free 982.7 MB)
15/08/05 11:30:26 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(34309) called with curMem=399000, maxMem=1030823608
15/08/05 11:30:26 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 33.5 KB, free 982.7 MB)
15/08/05 11:30:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 172.16.100.7:61775 (size: 33.5 KB, free: 983.0 MB)
15/08/05 11:30:26 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from collect at Hive.java:29
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoopcluster
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:547)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2625)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1783)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:885)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:884)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1255)
    at com.Hive.main(Hive.java:29)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoopcluster
    ... 44 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception indicates, the yarn-cluster mode cannot be used directly from the `SparkContext`. But you can run it on a standalone multi-node cluster using the `SparkContext`. First you have to start your standalone spark cluster and then you set `sparkConf.setMaster("spark://HOST:PORT")` where `HOST:PORT` is the URL of your spark cluster. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: ...I have tried as you said created a spark stanalone multi node cluster and tried to run this query by setting spark master url as spark://HOST:PORT. But it throws Unknown Host exception : hadoopcluster where hadoopcluster is the name of multinode hadoop cluster. Please find my error logs in my edited part of the question

Comment: I suspect that he cannot resolve the host name "hadoopcluster". Try to use the IP of the machine one which the master is running.

Comment: ...whether I have to add the ip of the hadoop master machines in the files such as core-site.xml

Comment: I don't think so. Either you have a DNS service running where you enter the mapping (IP to hostname) or you insert the mapping in your `hosts` file. But you have to insert it in all `hosts` files on each machine which has to do the name resolution.

Comment: I have checked the hosts file and I have already entered the list of ips in that. Also one important note is that hadoopcluster is the name of my cluster where I have defined it in fs.defaultFS in core-site.xml. <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
 <value>hdfs://hadoopcluster</value>
 </property>

Comment: I have solved that exception by copying hdf-site.xml to spark/conf folder

Comment: Thanks for helping me in solving this exception

Comment: I am querying data from hive using Apache spark sql and now the table holds 1 million rows and which grows periodically. So as of now I am using the above java code which throws memory related errors frequently. Can you suggest me how to solve this ?

Comment: Try not to use collect when you operate on really large RDDs. What collect does, is to send all the data of your RDD to your driver node. At some point this will be too big for your machine. If you still want to execute `collect`, then try to reduce the number of rows by sampling or applying a filter condition. If you should encounter memory problems on your worker nodes, then try to increase the available memory in the spark config. Alternatively, you can also increase the number of worker nodes to mitigate the problem.

Comment: Also I want to convert the entire row returned from the query to string. Is there any option in spark api? As I am using this in web service so I want to do this

Comment: @ Till Rohrmann...But row.toString never returns the value but it returns only the object