# Why does Jersey cause singleton class not working?

Tags: java, jersey, singleton

I implemented something like this:

```
@Path("/svc")
public class Service {

    Resource rsc = Resource.getInstance();

    @GET
    public String doGet() {...}
}

public class Resource {

    public static Resource instance;

    private Resource() {...}

    public static getInstance(){
        if (instance == null){
            return new Resource();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

`Service` class is the where the `GET` and `POST` methods are implemented, where `Resource` is the singleton class where some data is temporarily stored.

However, as I tested it, I found that the singleton class gets a new instance every time a method is called. The singleton class is just a classic Java singleton implementation. I know that adding the `@Singleton` annotation fixes the problem, but I was wondering what caused this behavior?

Comment: You are never assigning to `instance`

Comment: @Thilo Thank you, that was a silly mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

Your *singleton* is *not a singleton*.

### Long answer and how to fix it

The `instance` field is `public` and you are always returning a new `Resource` instance instead of assigning it to the `instance` field.

It's also recommended marking your class as `final` and using a synchronization in your `getInstance()` method:

```
public final class Resource {

    private static Resource instance;

    private Resource() {

    }

    public static synchronized Resource getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Resource();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

However, **it's not the best way to implement a singleton**.

For more information, refer to [**What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70689/1426227)

Comment: Thank you, realized that this morning... quite a silly mistake. And thanks for the additional resource.

Answer (score 1):

you have not assigning value to instance variable.

```
public class Resource{
      private static Resource instance;

      private Resource(){...}

      public static getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
    instance = new Resource();

        }
        return instance;
      }    
}
```

So, when you tries to `getInstance()` of Resource file. It is always null, which results in creating new object for class

Comment: should also make `instance` private. And think about multi-threaded access.

Comment: yes, you have to make it `private`. I have just added the instance value to solve problem mentioned in question. Inputs taken, thanks @Thilo

Answer (score 1):

A JAX-WS web service is by itself a Singleton. This means that all the request will be handled using a single web service instance (like a Servlet).
Refer to this link a detail answer is already here [Singleton Object in Java Web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096310/singleton-object-in-java-web-service)

By default Jersey creates a new instance of the resource class for every request. So if you don't annotate the Jersey resource class, it implicitly uses @RequestScoped scope. It is stated in Jersey documentation:

> Default lifecycle (applied when no annotation is present). In this
>   scope the resource instance is created for each new request and used
>   for processing of this request. If the resource is used more than one
>   time in the request processing, always the same instance will be used.
>   This can happen when a resource is a sub resource is returned more
>   times during the matching. In this situation only on instance will
>   server the requests.

Comment: I don't think that is true, unless you also annotate with `@Singleton`. See the discussion in the comments on the answer you linked to.